# Pytorch inceptionV3 transfer learning gives error - max() received an invalid combination of arguments

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

The program for transfer learning inception_v3 in pytorch that i am using is here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zn4z7nOp_wJne0En6zq4WJfwHVVftERT/view?usp=sharing

I am getting the following error upon running the program :

```
Epoch 0/24   
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-20-cc88ea5f8bd3> in <module>()
          1 model_ft = train_model(model_ft, criterion, optimizer_ft, exp_lr_scheduler,
    ----> 2                        num_epochs=25)

    <ipython-input-17-812cf3c4576a> in train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs)
         33                     outputs = model(inputs)
         34                     print(outputs)
    ---> 35                     _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
         36                     loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
         37 

    TypeError: max() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (tuple, int), but expected one of:
     * (Tensor input)
     * (Tensor input, Tensor other, Tensor out)
     * (Tensor input, int dim, bool keepdim, tuple of Tensors out)
```

How can this be fixed ?
Thank you

Comment: is your model output a torch Tensor?

Comment: It's solved now. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

in this case, I have changed the code as below and its worked for me,
Tutorial https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html

```
model_ft = models.inception_v3(pretrained=True)
model_ft.aux_logits=False
```

Comment: Why does this work? Does this hurt the model performance? The link you provided does not discuss this...

Comment: refer this
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-auxiliary-logits-set-to-false-in-train-mode/40705

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem from here: [pytorch inceptionv3](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/7be960f50388ed06ec3d349841786e0a525640f2/torchvision/models/inception.py#L125) int line 125.The error is when in train mod and aux_logits opening，it return (x, aux).
   I solved it by

1. use    `output, aux = model(input_var)`
2. if phase=='train':
      outputs,aux= model(inputs)
   else:
      outputs=model(inputs)

Answer (score 1):

```
model_ft.aux_logits=False

model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(2048, 2)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code your provided answers the question.

Comment: This is my experience with this problem. I have really no knowledge about the interior architecture of InceptionV3. Experimentally, the users copy the transfer-learning code of ResNet and change the ResNet name to Inception V3. Then they run the code and the error comes up. Therefore, they can fix the issue according to my experience.

Comment: "This is my experience" doesn't really explain how your code works. Why is it a good idea to set the `aux_logits` attribute to `False` and then call the `Linear` method. What do each of those things do? **How does this code work?**

Answer (score 0):

The line should be as shown below :

`_, preds = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)`